# Создание субдомена

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Возникла следующая проблема. На хостинге находится проект с каркасом .Net Framework 4 (переведенный с предыдущей версии хостером вручную), я захотел, создать субдомен, посредством создания виртуального каталога. При его создании по умолчанию используется .Net Framework 2.0, но мне нужно перевести его на .Net Framework 4. В тех. поддержке мне сказали сделать это самому вручную. Получается мне надо сделать изменение в файле web.config, подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно менять либо в Web.config либо (лучше) прямо в админке, при условии что она у вас конечно есть. Также зависит от того какой версии у вас IIS т.к. если он 6.0 то придется прописывать хэндлер (это уже точно не в Web.config), в то время как в IIS 7+ такой проблемы нет.

А субдомен и виртуальный каталог это вроде как разные вещи :)

Comment: В админке, пока нет возможности перейти на Framework 4, поэтому нужно сделать это вручную. IIS стоит 7.0, при этом я создал виртуальный каталог. Дело в том, что я не представляю, как в web.confige можно настроить Framework 4.